# Inline tag editing sometimes doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, editing

Lately, I had problems with inline editing of tags.

I hover the mouse close to the list of tags used in a question, I click on the "edit tags" link that appears, and I change the tags in the text field that is shown.
When I click on the "Save Tags Edits" button nothing happen: There is no indication that an AJAX request has been sent in background (the usual animation doesn't appear), and nothing happens if I click on the "Cancel" button too. If I refresh the page, the shown tags are still the original ones..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reproduce this and will have a fix soon -- it depends on alternating between inline edits, and inline tag edits.